# InsertNode function not insering a node in the right spot (automatically putting at the end)

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading, nodes

I have a linked list of `Courses` with multiple member functions such as CourseID, Prerequisites, Credit Hours, etc. I have these in a linked list and want to insert a new node in alphabetical order. I first ask the user to input all of the information for the class (member functions) and then I called my `InsertNode` function to add it to the list. I have overloaded the `operator>=` and `operator<`.

Here is my InsertNode function:

```
template <typename T>
void InsertNode(node<T>* &front, const T & value)
{
node<T>* newNode = CreateNode(value);

// if the list is empty or if insert in front of front  
if (front == NULL || front->nodeValue >= newNode->nodeValue) {
    newNode->next = front;
    front = newNode;
}
else
{
    //Locate the node before the point of insertion 

    node<T>* curr = front;
    while (curr->next != NULL && curr->next->nodeValue < newNode->nodeValue)
    {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    newNode->next = curr->next;
    curr->next = newNode;
    }
}
```

I have the user input each member function and call the `InsertNode` function like so:

```
    node<Course>* first;
    node<Course>* current;

    first = createLinkedList<Course>(lineCount);
    current = first;

    cin.ignore();
    cout << "Please input the Course Title: ";
    getline(cin, temp);
    c.setcourseTitle(temp);

    cout << "Please enter the Course ID: ";
    cin >> temp;
    c.setcourseID(temp);
    cout << "Please enter the Prerequisites: ";
    cin >> temp;
    c.setprerequisite(temp);


    cout << "Please enter the credit hours: ";
    cin >> credit;
    c.setcreditHours(credit);

    InsertNode(first, c);
```

my createdLinkedList function:

```
template <typename T>
node<T>* createLinkedList(int num)
{
    node<T> * front = NULL;
    for (int i = num; i > 0; i--) {
        front = new node<T>(T(), front);
    }
return front;
}
```

and here is my operator overloads:

```
bool operator<(const Course &lhs, const Course &rhs) {
    if (lhs.getcourseID() < rhs.getcourseID())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool operator>=(const Course &lhs, const Course &rhs) {
    if (lhs.getcourseID() >= rhs.getcourseID())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Declaration of node.h:

```
#ifndef NODE_CLASS
#define NODE_CLASS

#ifndef NULL
#include <cstddef>
#endif  // NULL

// linked list node
template <typename T>
class node
{
   public:
      T nodeValue;      // data held by the node
      node<T> *next;    // next node in the list

  // default constructor with no initial value
  node() : next(NULL)
  {}

  // constructor. initialize nodeValue and next
  node(const T& item, node<T> *nextNode = NULL) : 
          nodeValue(item), next(nextNode)
  {}
};

#endif   // NODE_CLASS
```

When I try to insert the node it is added to the back no matter what. Are my overloads not right? Any help would be great.

Comment: Isolated code fragments is insufficient information. You need to edit your question, and provide a [mcve].

Comment: How is this insufficient? I provided quite a bit of code?

Comment: Do you mean in alpha order of the course ID?

Comment: Yes alphabetically, so I would be inserting a Course ID COSC220, which would be inserted between COSC120 and COSC350.

Comment: Unless someone can reproduce the issue themselves, this is insufficient. The question clearly fails the "Complete" requirement for a [mcve]. For example, you could have a bug in your `getCourseId()`, so that the resulting comparison is always false. Or, there's some kind of a problem with the operator overload. C++ is a complicated language. I see nothing technically wrong with the shown code (although a few things can be improved). Therefore, the problem must be in the code that's not shown. Which is why a [mcve] is required. Did I mention that you need to include a [mcve]?

Comment: So i should just post the 1000 lines of code I have then?

Comment: What do `node` and specifically `nodeValue` look like?

Comment: will add the definition of node.h above

Comment: No, not 1000 lines, because that would clearly violate the "Minimal" requirement of a [mcve].

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in what you have posted, I agree with Sam, try to make a MCVE - you might even find your problem in the course of making it.

Comment: After the update - why are you inserting `lineCount` blank items in your linked list? Your new items will be added after the blank ones, as the new items will sort later.

Comment: I have to read items in from a file, so I just read through each line on the file to know how many nodes to originally create from the file. Thats all that `lineCount` is for.

Comment: You don't need to create nodes in advance - your `InsertNode` does that when you add the node.

Comment: Zack, on the MCVE. It's not just for us out here. Knowing how to isolate a bug is a vital debugging skill. The act of producing a MCVE almost always exposes the bug and leaves one groaning at their idiocy before fixing it. And the times where it doesn't, THAT is what Stack Overflow is for.